# PHP Multidimensional Array - "Exchange" Dimensions

Tags: php

I'm wondering what the best way is of doing this:

```
$fc['abc'][0] = 1;
$fc['xyz'][0] = 2;
$fc['abc'][1] = 3;
$fc['xyz'][1] = 4;

$fc2 = something($fc);

print $fc2[0]['abc']; // 1
```

In other words, the `something` function will swap the two dimensions round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but this works:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($fc as $key1 => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key2 => $num) {
        $result[$key2][$key1] = $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I've tested this and it does work. Like you, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way though!

Answer (score -2):

array_flip() ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: No, this doesn't work because array_flip won't work with multidimensional arrays, you get an error.